# Can WebRTC be used in the server side for fetching stream frames?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, video-processing, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I would like to make a camera stream from the browser (PC / Mac / Android), to a Java server in order to run some CV algo on the frames?

Is WebRTC would be a good solution for that, I know that it's mostly used for a 2-endpoint communication solution. But I was wondering if I can use it only for one direction for a Java server that somehow can handle each frame of the stream?

Any known solutions \ project?

Is there another good tech (both cross platform client and Java server) for live streaming and analysis?

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:

1) ignore WebRTC and its peer-to-peer (or peer-to-server) capabilities, grab the frame locally and use HTTP to send it to the server. https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/ has the details for that.

2) use WebRTC to transfer an actual stream to the other side. This requires the server to understand WebRTC. https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/tutorials/java/tutorial-magicmirror.html shows an example, even written in Java.

The http-post approach is simpler but the bandwidth requirements make it somewhat unsuitable for high-fps applications.

Comment: Thanks for the options, I did try them both before. The first option doesn't take advantage of the encoders making the bandwidth to big and the transfer rate too low. I already checked Kurento the middleware level is in Java, the Real engine (Kurento Media Server) runs in C

Comment: And need to extend it to make a special module to take frame and process it,,not the easy using C... And I'm not sure how to scale this solution and what is the maximum capacity using one server media.

Answer (score -1):

This is answered infinite times all over the web; of course you can get the frames when you implement the WebRTC in your server code, most probably by using [Google's WebRTC native API](https://web.archive.org/web/20191129201540/https://webrtc.org/native-code/).

So it's still peer-to-peer, but one peer is a web browser, another peer is your server. The real issue that probably invalidates your idea, is that you are receiving a highly compressed video (VP8/VP9/H264), so you will get raw frames after decompression, so what quality CV can you expect from working on these frames?

Comment: I know the google webrtc lib for Android, but didn't find any example of a server that gets the stream (preferred in Java). My CV model is working on a raw individual frame so I will need access \ feed it with individual frames after decompression

Comment: Sure, I am just saying the decompressed frames will have artifacts caused by compression. But if you wanna do that, the WebRTC native code has sample projects where you receive raw I420 video frames.

Comment: I can't find there an example one how to do it on a server, I found several example doing so in the client side

Comment: In the WebRTC native codebase, go to webrtc\examples\peerconnection\client. In the file main_wnd.cc you can see MainWnd::VideoRenderer::OnFrame which receives I420 video frame - that's where you get your frame. https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/examples/peerconnection/client/main_wnd.cc

Comment: https://webrtc.org/native-code/ broken link, Do you mean https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/index.md?